# Set MSI installation directory to 3rd Party / Sister Product installation folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, custom-action

Our product deploys via msi at clients' sites, and is an add-on to a sister product.

I need to detect the install folder of the sister product at install time, and install our product to the same location.

Comment: Are you using (*shudder*) the built in Visual Studio Setup Project? Or another MSI build system (e.g. Wix, Installshield, etc)?

Comment: Thank you for putting a name to that uncomfortable feeling I get when running builds. Yes, we use the built in deployment project system. Our approach needs to twin the sister product, so we don't have the option of using an alternative msi build system.

Comment: I believe that, if your sticking with VS Setups, you'd have to write a custom action to do a registry search for the other product, and then set the install location. With e.g. WiX, there's built in support for doing these searches to set property values. (Hint - even if you can't change the "sister product"'s install, you might want to consider changing *your* install to use e.g. WiX (other products exist, I'm just recommending the one I'm used to - and it's free)

Comment: It can't be done using just VDPROJ. :-(  See, while VDPROJ exposes LaunchConditions, it doesn't expose AppSearch. So write a custom action you say?  Sorry, again.  VDPROJ only exposes CA's to run as "install, uninstall, rollback and commit" which is too late to do a search and change the installation directory.  You would have to use a merge module ( WiX!! ) to inject this capability into a VDPROJ msi.  See my answer below.  The only alternative is to start doing postbuild MSI tweaks to author the AppSerach and SetDirectory CA's.

Comment: PS- VDPROJ is gone in the next version of VS.  I suggest looking at InstallShield LE and WiX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this blog article I wrote:

[Redemption of Visual Studio Deployment Projects](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/03/redemption-of-visual-studio-deployment.html)

This will allow you to "twin" your sister product to the naked eye but under the covers get all the advantages of a WiX project.  This includes full use of custom search extensions and custom action scheduling.

Comment: Thanks for this; our sister product wasn't aware that vdproj was about to be [deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx). We'll be moving the whole suite to WiX.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar some time ago: I had an NSIS Installer which queried a specific regkey to get the current installation dir of my app. When the key and it's value existed, i passed it via "/TARGETDIR=..." to the Msi setup.
(Background was, that the user can change the installation dir during setup and i wanted his last dir to be the default in the installdir page of the installer)

hth